# How to receive notifications from an NSMutableArray subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, key-value-observing

I have subclassed NSMutableArray to allow for a datasource. This is called BaseObjectArray. The array actually only holds a list of rowids (as uint64_t), and when asking for objectAtIndex it asks the datasource delegate for the object with that rowid (to allow for lazy DB queries).

The internal list of rowids is a class in it's own right (a RowIDSet, or the OrderedRowIDSet subclass, which is just a subclass of NSObject), that maintains just the list of unique rowids.

What I need is to somehow listen for changes to the BaseObjectArray (which is actually listening to changes on it's RowIDSet object, perhaps through a similar method).

As objects may be added/removed from the BaseObjectArray not using the standard addObject:, but instead with addRowID:, the object that owns the BaseObjectArray will probably not get standard KVO notifications.

Possible solutions I have considered:

1. The BaseObjectArray has owner and ownerKey properties, and the BaseObjectArray triggers [owner willChangeForKey:ownerKey]; whenever anything changes.
2. Use will/didChangeNotificationBlocks - listeners can simply add a block to the BaseObjectArray (retaining these blocks in an NSMutableArray), and all the blocks in this array are triggered when something in the BaseObjectArray changes. I am uncertain about the possible retain-cycle nightmare that may ensue.
3. KVO on a 'contents' property of the BaseObjectArray. Anyone wanting to observe the BaseObjectArray actually observes the keyPath 'contents', and inside the BOArray it calls [self willChangeForKeyPath:@"contents"]. The contents property just returns self.
4. ... something obvious that i have missed ...

Please let me know if any of these make the most (or any) sense, or if there is a better solution out there.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you know what you are doing, you should *not* subclass `NSMutableArray`. `NSMutableArray` is a class cluster and requires [special treatment](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-03-12-subclassing-class-clusters.html).

Why not just create a custom object that uses a plain `NSMutableArray` as its storage class? There seems to be no good reason to subclass `NSMutableArray` in your case, but maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I (hope I) know what i'm doing when subclassing NSMutableArray - all the necessary methods are overridden. I am actually not using any of the original array functionality - I can't just use plain NSMutableArray as storage because my goal is to not have storage, instead having a datasource that lazily gets the data when needed. The simple reason I am subclassing arrays rather than NSObject is to be able to use this class in existing code that expects arrays. My main pain is that NSArrays throw an exception if you call addObserver on them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, but if it does, it's probably the best way.

Make sure your NSMutableArray subclass is KVC compliant for the key `self` (if this doesn't work for `self` add a new property e.g `rows` which returns self or a copy of self).  To make self (or whatever new property you use) KVC compliant you need to follow the [Indexed To-Many Relationship Compliance rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172-SW2)  for mutable ordered collections:

- Implement a method named - that returns an array.
- Or have an array instance variable named  or _.
- Or implement the method -countOf and one or both of -objectInAtIndex: or -AtIndexes:.
- Optionally, you can also implement -get:range: to improve performance.

`self` ticks the box on the first of these.  Also:

- Implement one or both of the methods -insertObject:inAtIndex: or -insert:atIndexes:.
- Implement one or both of the methods -removeObjectFromAtIndex: or -removeAtIndexes:.
- ptionally, you can also implement -replaceObjectInAtIndex:withObject: or -replaceAtIndexes:with: to improve performance

So you'll need e.g. `-insertObject:inSelfAtIndex:` and `-removeObjectFrom<Key>AtIndex:`

Then you can use [manual KVO notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-SW3) wherever you want to notify obeservers of the `self` property on that object.  So you might use

```
NSIndexSet* indexes = // index set containing the index or indexes of objects to remove
[self willChange: NSKeyValueChangeRemoval valuesAtIndexes: indexes forKey:@"self"];
```

when removing objects.

Comment: If this works it sounds great, but unfortunately i'm having trouble implementing. Inside the BaseObjectArray I am successfully triggering the will/didChange methods whenever something in the internal rowIDSet changes. From the outside I am not seeing any changes. Say it is a property called boarray on the container - in the container I say [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"boarray" options:0 context:NULL], but none of the will/didChange calls make it out. eg. in your example, how would i observe the [self willChange...forKey:@"self"], which is being called from inside the BOArray class?

Comment: @Loz: Have you overridden `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:` ?  It needs to return `NO` for your property.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002299-BBCGIHJF